# Частица "не" меняет смысл слова изнутри?

Tags: причастия

Два примера для сопоставления:

> **Неудовлетворённые** парни - парни **неудовлетворённы**

Согласно имеющимся данным (МАС, Ефремова, Кузнецов), слово **"неудовлетворенный"** является только *прилагательным*.
Безусловно, подставить "очень" получается, значит качество-признак здесь точно есть: *"не испытывающий удовлетворения"*, однако:

---

Трудно себе представить, что это **обыкновенное прилагательное**, ведь, даже трактуя данное понятие, мы используем слово, включающее в себе процесс, - "испытывающий".

---

Следовательно, у меня закралась мысль, что слово ***"неудовлетворенный"*** вообще не используется в письменной речи как прилагательное ввиду специфики своего значения, близкого по характеру глагольному, а потому я делаю вывод, что в языке употребляется лишь ***причастие "удовлетворенный"***, которое пишется слитно с "не" при отсутствии зависимых слов.

---

**Причастие** полностью отражает суть значения глагола "удовлетворить", понимание *"удовлетворенности"*: *парни, которых не удовлетворили, что-то не удовлетворило, которые не удовлетворились* (пусть даже для страдательных причастие это значение не совсем актуально).